# Google Chrome: CSS rendering bug with table and border-collapse

Tags: css, google-chrome

[here's my snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/rstLj3y0/1/)

the table's CSS is:

```
table{
  font-family:tahoma;
  font-size:20px;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  background:white;
}
```

[image]

Seems like a new rendering bug to me, didn't have this problem with earlier versions of Chrome.
Why does it render strange gaps (instead of collapsing) and render thicker lines although it shouldn't?

zoomed effect:

[image]

Is there a workaround?

Comment: seems this is indeed a Chrome Bug (just stumbled upon it myself). Chromium Issue 1238502 outlines a similar behavior - but got merged into the underlying "border snapping before layout" investigation (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1201762)